# Batch - Replace specific char in a specific sub directory

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a script that will copy line by line all files in a subdirectory from an original_file folder to a converted_file folder and upon seeing a |, will replace it with a ; .. but so far no luck, the second loop doesn't seem to function.

```
ORIGINAL = path to the original_file folder
CONVERTED = path to the converted_file folder


for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b %ORIGINAL%') do (
        FOR /F "tokens=*" %%B IN ('%ORIGINAL%\%%f') DO (
            SET CCC=%%B
            SET CCC=!CCC:^|=^;!
            ECHO !CCC! >> '%CONVERTED%\%%f'
        )
)
```

My first loop works fine, sends all the file names in the original_folder, yet my second loop isn't used. I tried to play with ' and " for files/path containing spaces.

Any ideas on how one would fix this only using classic old batch technics?

Comment: Change your inner loop to `FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%B IN ("%ORIGINAL%\%%f") DO ( ... )` (the `'` is used to mark a command; together with the `usebackq` option, `"` mark files; type `for /?` in a command prompt window and read the help very carefully)... Furthermore, I recommend the quoted `set` syntax `SET "CCC=!CCC:|=;!"`, so no more escaping is necessary...

Comment: That did the trick thanks :) - when using the double quotes and usebackq option, it longer failed to find the right path/driver/file/etc..

Answer (score 0):

Using this did the trick, thanks @aschipfl

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b %ORIGINAL%') do (
        FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%B IN ("%ORIGINAL%\%%f") DO (
                SET CCC=%%B
                SET "CCC=!CCC:%CHAR_TO_REPLACE%=%CHAR_TO_USE%!"
                ECHO !CCC! >> "%CONVERTED%\%%f"
            )
    )
```